# unable to read csv with double quotes

Tags: java, arrays

I need a solution.. The problem is in csv file product values are saperated with double quotes so my code is unable to read full product value its only reading "Marlin - 12" but full product name is "Marlin - 12"" - Custom".

```
PRODUCT_ID,CATEGORY,PRODUCT, MIN_STOCK_LEVEL
23,         cat1,  "Marlin - 12"" - Custom",2
24,         cat1,  "Marlin - 12"" – Custom1",3
25,         cat2,  "Marlin - 12"" – Custom2",3
26,         cat3,  "Marlin - 12"" – Custom3",2
27,         cat4,  "Marlin - 12"" - Custom",2
28,         cat5,  "Marlin - 12"" - Custom",2
```

Code im using for reading csv file is

```
import com.Ostermiller.util.CSVParser

...

else if ( fileName.contains(".csv")) {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    CSVParser csvp = new CSVParser(fis);
    String[][] values = csvp.getAllValues();
    tempClientProductCol = new ClientProductCol();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV format seems to be the one specified in [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). According to the [Ostermiller site](https://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html), you would have to use the Excel style. It is documented how to use it there. You would end up using [`ExcelCSVParser`](https://ostermiller.org/utils/javadoc/ExcelCSVParser.html).

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted as it seems right to me :-)

Comment: Was mine, I thought you suggest a new library containing this parser, I added link to javadoc to clarify (and be able to remove downvote). `:)`

Comment: Also tested and working great so removing my workaround answer

Comment: I dint get you.. can you please tell me what should i do now?

Comment: @eshwarchettri just replace `CSVParser csvp = new CSVParser(fis);` by     `ExcelCSVParser csvp = new ExcelCSVParser(fis);` and you will get your problem solved

Comment: Mmm... You had no error just bad data... And I tested solution and works ok, you imported new parser?

Comment: Glad to hear, bus @spa is the man here. Also, think about accepting the answer if you solved it ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is not problem in CSV File or CSVParser..It happend when you set the value to your pojo..
The Working code here

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path.csv");
CSVParser csvp = new CSVParser(fis);
String[][] values = csvp.getAllValues();    
System.out.println(values[1][2]);
```